# Amazon Kindle (Android) Screen Unresponsive to Touch After Many Activity Changes

Tags: android, screen, kindle-fire, kindle

I have a Unity game, and when it runs on an Amazon Kindle device, after several activity changes, the screen becomes unresponsive.

It has a low occurrence rate, but when I am able to reproduce it, it's either by initiating an In-App-Billing pop-up screen (the standard Amazon one), opening up the Facebook/Twitter post pop-ups, or switching across different applications.

I'm pretty sure that the device is in a state where it is confused what activity is on top and is taking input. Would that be correct?

The game isn't crashed at all, I can still see things animating, and the OS back button properly navigates backwards through the screens all the way to the exit prompt.

Comment: which device (gingerbread or ICS based) and have you checked that when the pop-up closes the app isn't simply losing focus? Does the same thing happen on other Android devices?

Comment: Seems to only happen on my Kindle Fire devices, both the HD and non-HD versions.

I believe the issue is that the app has indeed lost focus, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get focus back. Even if I go to the home screen and come back, the app still won't accept input.

Comment: When I get into this state, my touch count is zero. I have a log message in the camera's update that gets called every 3 seconds, and that continues to log, but the log message I placed inside the for loop of the touch count stops getting called once I am in this state.

So somehow the touches are never getting registered to Unity's Input